# What is the efficient way to get the diff of two arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

**Sample Input**

```
Array_1 [] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
Array_2 [] = { 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 };
```

**Sample Output**

```
Array_1_Extras [] = { 10, 20 };
Array_2_Extras [] = { 60, 70 };
```

**Description**

1. Input Arrays are not sorted.
2. Input Arrays Length - 10K.
3. Input Array values range 0 - 4095.
4. Input Array orders and values should not be modified.
5. Output Arrays can be in any order.
6. Duplicates not needed in the Output Arrays.

I need some time efficient logic for this program. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the arrays sorted? Are they strictly integer? Are the numbers bounded?

Comment: Will all numbers be positive? Do they have an upper limit? Is it OK to change array ordering?

Comment: Is the length of either array bounded?

Comment: *Sigh*... What have you tried?

Comment: Input array length = 10??? I would say O(n^2) bruteforce without any "efficient" tricks. 100 iterations is nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "time efficient"?  If your input length is bounded by a small constant (i.e. 10), then asymptotic complexity is moot.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Sorry it was 10K, wrongly put.

Comment: Ok, now we are talking..

Comment: Then, as I understand the elements are not unique? How are you handling two identical elements?

Comment: "diff" (in the question's title) is not the better word for your problem, imho... Something like "mutual exclusion" would be better

Comment: 4 "too broad" close votes? Is it really that broad?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple `O(N)` time algorithm somewhat space consuming (it is taking in account duplicates as well).

1) Declare an array `C` of zeros of length `4096`.
2) Iterate on first array `A` and for each element indexed `i` *increment* `C[A[i]]`
3) Iterate second array `B`, and for each element `i` *decrement*  `C[B[i]]`
4) Iterate over `C` and `i` of negative `C[i]` will indicate an element of `B - A`, and of positive one will indicate an element of `A - B`
* And the absolute value will indicate the difference in the dupes number, if you are interested..

Comment: Regarding the duplicates: I think that if you have, say, three 10s in the first array and only one in the second, 10 shouldn't appear in either difference, because the arrays are treated as sets. Your answer will consider 10 as element of `A - B`.

Comment: @MOehm Yes. It depends on the definition of the problem. Using your definition the elements of `C` should be bounded between `-1` and `1`. Update: Actually no..The iteration over the second array should just reset the value.. But then we won't get the symmetric result. We will if we add extra check. anyway, I believe it demonstrates the overall idea.

Comment: Yes. I guess the problem wasn't well stated in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an O(n) implementation:

```
int seen[4096];
memset(seen, 0, sizeof(seen));
int a[10000], b[10000];
size_t aSize, bSize;
... // Fill a and b
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != aSize ; i++) {
    seen[a[i]] |= 1;
}
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != bSize ; i++) {
    seen[b[i]] |= 2;
}
size_t j = 0;
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != aSize ; i++) {
    if (seen[a[i]] == 1) {
        a[j++] = a[i];
    }
}
aSize = j;
j = 0;
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != bSize ; i++) {
    if (seen[b[i]] == 2) {
        b[j++] = b[i];
    }
}
bSize = j;
```

This approach deletes all numbers in `a` that are also in `b`, regardless of their count. It also keeps duplicates. For example, if the input is like this

```
a = [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30 , 40]
b = [10, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50]
```

the output will be

```
a = [20, 20, 20]
b = [50]
```

Answer (score 0):

For input arrays of size 10000, you are fairly likely to be able to judge by asymptotic complexity of the general algorithm.

The naive algorithm is to iterate over one array, scanning the other for appearances of each element, then to reverse roles and do it again.  If the ratio of the size of the longer array to the size of the shorter array is `O(1)`, then this approach has cost bounded by `O(n`<sup>`2`</sup>`)`.

You could solve the problem at `O(n log n)` cost by creating copies of the input arrays (`O(n)`), sorting them (`O(n log n)`), and performing one joint linear scan of the sorted arrays, similar to the merge step of a merge sort (`O(n)`).

Given that the values from the input arrays are drawn from a relatively small range, however, it is reasonable to consider a solution that is `O(n)` overall:

1. create an array with one 2-bit or wider bitfield element per possible input-array value
2. scan the first input array; for each value set bit zero of the bitfield corresponding to that value
3. scan the second input array; for each value set bit one of the bitfield corresponding to that value
4. scan the bitfield array: the elements tell you whether the corresponding input value appears in both input arrays, in exactly one, or in neither.

Answer (score 0):

1. sort the arrays (or a copy if you cannot change the originals)
2. walk them recursively until they're done

For each recursion, take the first element of each array.

a. if they're different add the smaller to either `array_1_extras` or `array_2_extras` and advance the array with that element
b. if they're equal, **mind duplicates** and advance both arrays