# Compute two set differences A\B and B\A in one pass

Tags: c++, algorithm

If I have a set represented as a sorted range, I can use `std::set_difference` to compute `A\B` and `std::set_symmetric_difference` to compute `A\B U B\A`. What if I want to compute both distinct sets `A\B` and `B\A`?

Of course, I can run `std::set_difference` twice, but this does not seem very elegant (and not even possible if we have e.g. input iterators). It is also pretty easy to write my own implementation, but I wonder whether there is a ready solution for this task?

Comment: Please provide a good sample code please everyone can work with! What's _more elegant_ might come out as opinion based anyways.

Comment: "It doesn't seem very elegant." I'm inclined to disagree. IMHO it's easy to read and satisfies a "do one thing" itch I have.

Comment: You may find this recent question useful, especially if the range of the values in the set is limited: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615915/what-is-the-efficient-way-to-get-the-diff-of-two-arrays-in-c

Comment: @AndyG In some cases - yes. But suppose we have input iterators. In this case we _must_ do this in one pass.

Comment: TTBOMK, no.  Libraries have to balance feature-richness against overall size, since the latter affects how comprehensible they are.  A good criterion is usually "Can the thing you want to do already be done with separate function calls that don't increase the asymptotic time complexity?"  Here the answer is yes.  (There are only a few exceptions, e.g. `minmax`.)

Comment: @Mikhail Declaritive style programming can be "elegant" -- calling `set_difference` twice conveys right away what you're doing.

Comment: slight generalization: `disentangle(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2, Out1 d1, Out2 d2, Out3 d3)` where the 3 output iterators give the two set differences and the set intersection.

Comment: @TemplateRex Yes, this would also be useful.

Comment: an even better algorithm would be `matched_merge` taking two input ranges `A` and `B` (4 iterators) and an output iterator. The output is not sorted as in regular `merge`, but `3-way` partitioned. The algorithm could return 3 iterators to the starts of the 3 segments that contain the `A\B`, `B\A` and `A&B` parts. I think there should be a name for that in the relational database world (some form of join / merge). I think it should be `O(N)` in the total input size.

Comment: @TemplateRex For me it is not clear how to efficiently implement such `matched_merge` without `O(N)` unnecessary moves of the elements, because we do not know the size of `A\B` at the beginning of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

If your sets are both sorted it can be done in one pass using two iterators:

- If the pointed element is in both sets, increase both
- else if the element pointed by A's iterator is smaller, produce it to A\B, and increase A's iterator.
- else, increase produce B's element to B\A and increase B's iterator.

C++ like Pseudo code:

```
iter1 = A.begin();
iter2 = B.begin();
while (iter1 != A.end() && iter2 != B.end()) { 
  if (*iter1 == *iter2) { 
    // don't produce anything
    ++iter1; ++iter2;
  } else if (*iter1 < *iter2) { 
    // produce *iter1 to A\B
    ++iter1;
  } else { 
    //produce *iter2 to B\A
    ++iter2;
  }
}

while (iter1 != A.end()) {
  //produce element to A\B
  ++iter1;
}
while (iter2 != B.end()) {
  //produce element to B\A
  ++iter2;
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, as I've said, "pretty easy to write". I asked about some ready implementations. The thing is they are pretty hard to google.

Comment: @AndyG If your set supports `O(n)` iteration of the entire list, and it's already sorted, it's `O(n)` (If I remember correctly, std::set does guarantee both, but I might be wrong)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was imagining needing to perform binary search for each check of element in other list.